# Why is the result not being displayed based on the condition given?

Tags: c, if-statement

I tried making a code to find the marks of the students and display the marks, average, total marks and result. But, I am having trouble displaying the correct results. Even if I follow the condition the result is always displayed as Fail. I don't know where I made the mistake. I would be grateful if someone could fix the issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the total number of students:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int marks[n][5],i,j,sum[40]={0};
    float average[40];
    int result;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter marks of student %d\n",i+1);//To get the marks of the students
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("marks[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &marks[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum[i]=sum[i]+marks[i][j];//To calculate the total marks
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            average[i]=sum[i]/5.0;//To find the average
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if(marks[i][j] < 50){//Condition to check if a student has passed or not
                result = 0;
                break;
            }             
        }
    }
    printf("SNo\tCPL101\tACS101\tEGP101\tPHY101\tMAT101\tSum\tAverage\tResults\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n%d",i+1);
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d", marks[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\t%d\t%.2f\t", sum[i],average[i]);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            printf("Fail");
        }
        else{
            printf("Pass");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have one variable `result`. After you set it to `0` once, it will never change again and when you come to the loop for printing, you will always print the same value. And generally, you never set it to `1` or intitilize it at all.

Comment: `result` will be either uninitialized (UB) or assigned to `0` if `marks[i][j] < 50` at that point. What value do you expect `result` to have ?

Comment: oh, so what changes should I make?

Comment: You need to move this `if(marks[i][j] < 50) { ... }` part into the loop where you print the results. And you need to initialize for each student.

Comment: When computing the average, the inner `j` loop makes no sense.  It's just doing the same thing 5 times for no reason.  `j` isn't even used (except to control the loop).  Get rid of the inner loop.

Comment: Your handling of `result` isn't right.  Two problems:  (1) it's never initialized to `1`, so the value starts out undefined.  It may be set to `0`, or it may remain undefined.  (2) You want it to be an array, so that each student can pass or fail independent of the other students.  Right now there's only one `result`, but it's printed for each student.  That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @TanishSharma This isn't really a matter of programming knowledge or experience.  It's just basic common sense reasoning.  I explained the problems in clear, concise English.  You just need to make more of an effort to understand them and fix them yourself.

Comment: @TomKarzes roger that

Answer (score 0):

1. Nowhere do you check whether n >= 40. So if someone were to enter, say, 100, you'd be overrunning the `sum[]` and `average[]` arrays, and probably crashing the program.
2. Instead of embedding these `40` constants, it's best practice to use a single identifier so that there's no risk of things getting out of step. So, for example, using `#define MAX_STUDENTS 40`, and using that to size `sum[]` and `average[]`.
3. That said, you'd be better off allocating all three arrays dynamically, based on the value of `n`, using `malloc(3)`.
4. I don't know what you intended to do with `result`, but it's not doing what you intended! You need one of these per student.
5. To my mind, you'd be far better off creating a `struct` definition that holds the result for a student: it contains a `marks[5]` array, and members for `average`, `sum` and `result`. Then you have only one `calloc(3)` for the array of these structs (which also zeroes it), and you can iterate over it for your final output. So much easier!